# Lightwieght serializable and parse friendly datastructure for storing server control properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-structures, controls, viewstate

I am using asp.net server controls and don't want to store the server control properties in dreaded and hogging viewstate. So i need somekind of datastructure in c# to store those properties and serialize them into a client hidden state. Has someone done a study on which would give me the best Performance, remove redundant keys and which provides easy serialize/deserialize process also provide security from it being tampered. SessionState is not a good option for this, for people who want to go that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to store the data in client hidden state.  ViewState does exactly this: and I think Microsoft designed it to be compact.  What makes you think you can do better?

IMHO there's no silver bullet, if you want to store the state client-side, stick to ViewState.

Comment: i do agree but some preliminary tests showed that adding single character to viestate resulted in hidden field adding up upto 10 characters how is that bandwidth friendly to say. Also why not serialize a `List<String>` which are my property to Json format and store it on the hidden field, retrieve it back then

Comment: @Deeptechtons, You have to remember that when you store one character of data in ViewState, it also needs to store metadata to describe what that character represents.  By being selective about which controls enable ViewState, it's usually possible to achieve acceptable page size.  Any home-grown solution is likely to be less secure and less maintainable - ViewState was designed by some smart engineers.

Comment: Agree 100%, OP is trying to reinvent the wheel here.  If you aren't satisfied with the size of your viewstate, it's probably because you don't have it tweaked properly.  This article was very helpful to me:  http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can define a simple class, serialize the instance into a binary and do a Base64 encoding of that binary and use it in the hidden field. If you want to protect against tampering, I would suggest to include another hidden field containing a hash constructed out of the serialized data and a key which you can keep on the server side. You can then construct the same key again upon the form post and compare with the one you received in the hidden field.

Comment: I am sure there is a builtin datastructure way more faster than me creating a class for this. because it basically drills down to strings nothing more

Comment: Perhaps you can use `List<string>`. You can pretty much use any builtin data type that is marked `Serializable` with the above method.